# Will Web.Config be locked when a request is accessing it

Tags: asp.net

will the web.Config of an application will be locked , when a request is accessing it.Do other requests needs to wait in queue? till the request before was processed?

what is the General Process .. if two Resources are accessing an object in Web.Config at same time what will happen?

Comment: do you need to lock configuration?

Comment: How can we achieve this , what is the general Process asp.net follow? .. will it lock it?

Comment: what is the General Process .. if two Resources are accessing an object in Web.Config at same time what will happen?

Comment: How do you access web.config - can you show us some code, or at least a class?

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Lock ASP.NET Configuration Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178693.aspx)

```
You can lock configuration settings in ASP.NET configuration files (Web.config files) 
by adding an allowOverride attribute to a location element and setting the
allowOverride attribute to false. Then within the location element, you 
can define the configuration section that you want to lock. ASP.NET will 
throw an exception if another configuration file attempts to override any 
configuration section that is defined within this locked location element.
```

---

```
<configuration>
  <location path="application1" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <trust level="High" />
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="application2" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <trust level="Medium" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you , But what is the General Process .. if two Resources are accessing an object in Web.Config at same time what will happen?